accordion in jira plugin via velocity template
I am making an information panel in Jira, but due to the large amount of information, it can take up a lot of space on the page. Is it possible to somehow collapse it using the html element "accordion"? Im trying it, but it doesnt work.
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
   incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
   exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
 incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
 exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
            panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
            panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    });
}
</script> 

